# Query SendGrid API based on Message ID

Tags: c#, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

So I am moving to SendGrid for my email service and when I send an email, my response object creates an X-Message-Id in the event the email was queued up successfully. However that doesnt account for bounced emails so.

```
static async Task SendEmail()
{
    var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiKey"];
    var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
    var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
    var subject = "Hello World from the Twilio SendGrid CSharp Library Helper!";
    var to = new EmailAddress("testUser@recipient.com", "Jeeno");
    var plainTextContent = "Hello, Email from the helper [SendSingleEmailAsync]!";
    var htmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email from the helper! [SendSingleEmailAsync]</strong>";
    var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);

    var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    Console.WriteLine(msg.Serialize());
    Console.WriteLine("============================================1");
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine("============================================2");
    Console.WriteLine(response.Headers);
    Console.WriteLine("============================================3");
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress <Enter> to continue.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I would like to create a scheduled task to then query for all bounced emails and pull them back based on that or really any ID. However when hitting the sendgrip api endpoint for bounced emails I am only getting a response object with a timestamp, email string, reason string, and status string. Is there not a way to query that based on Message Id?

```
static async Task Execute()
{
    var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiKey"];
    var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

    string queryParams = @"{
    }";
    var response = await client.RequestAsync(method: SendGridClient.Method.GET, urlPath: "/suppression/bounces", queryParams: queryParams);
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

3 options:

1. [Subscribe to Webwook events](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/) where SendGrid will post your api back events for the message. When you send the message request you can include custom_args (apiV3) or unique_ids (apiV2) to uniquely identify the email you are sending. The Webhook response will have your unique id in it so you can tie up your original email and the resulting events
2. If Webhooks are a little too unreliable for you, you can pay for the Add-on to use the EmailActivity History Api. This will allow you to query another Sendgrid API to get a list of messages and the last time they were updated, [or get a message by MessageId or by your uniqueId as per (1)](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/email-activity/filter-all-messages). I believe you get up to 30 days of history, so if you are regularly querying you can store your response locally before the data disappears from the server.
3. Send the email and check the response headers for the X-Message-ID value. This is the value Sendgrid assigns the message before it individually sends it to each recipient (which then generates a 'MessageId' or sg_message_id). You can then query the EmailActivity History Api to GET /messages with a query= `msg_id like "{X-Message-Id}%"` e.g. `msg_id like "abc-123-def%"`.

Comment: Sarin, Could you provide me full code using c# for option 3.  

Query for the EmailActivity History Api to GET /messages with a query= msg_id like "{X-Message-Id}%" e.g. msg_id like "abc-123-def%"

Comment: Could you please provide us C# code for sendgrid webhook event so that i can track my email by X-Message-Id

Comment: @RaselAhmed please refer to the SendGrid website for help documentation on their api. In regards to making calls from your c# code, you should refer to the help documentation for the specific HTTP component you are using to check the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

SendGrid doesn't have a way to query by `message_id`. Provided on the receipt, so that you can relate it to the events you receive via the [Event Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/event/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, using the LIKE operator

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/messages?limit=1&query=msg_id%20LIKE%20%22MSG_ID%25%22' \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer <<YOUR_SENDGRID_API_KEY_HERE>>' \
  --data '{}'
```